# Fit more notification icons on status bar

Tags: notifications, notification-icons

I have a xiaomi mi a3, recently updated to android 11. Before updating to android 11, on android 10, the limit of the notification icons that would show, at the left side of the status bar was 4 icons[image]. Now, after updating to android 11, I can see max 2 icons[image: 2 icons] followed by a dot if there are more than 2 notifications. Is there any way to "increase" the limit? I would like to have 4 instead of 2. Is there any way **without rooting please?** I don't want to root my phone. Maybe an ADB command would do that?